# How to send json String from jsp page to Spring mvc controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring, jsp

I am trying to pass a simple json string to my controller,but it is not getting at there.I have a lot of other fields like inserting deleting etc inside my controller code,all of them will works perfectly,except this Json receiving.I tried a lot but not able to find out.I checked the path given and its correct.Is anything wrong with my controller code?Any help will be highly appreciable

My jsp code

```
var obj=new Object();
    obj.sm=startMonth;
    obj.sd=startDay;
    obj.em=endMonth;
    obj.ed=endDay;

 var jsonDate= JSON.stringify(obj);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',      
        dataType: 'json',
        url:"/proj/test/dateVerification",
        data:jsonDate,

        success: function(jsonDate) {//upto this line from my browser debugger it works
            if (response == jsonDate)
            {
            alert("success and json passed");
            } else {
            alert("not success"+response);
            }
        },
        error:function(xhr, errorType, exception) { 

            alert("inside error function 1(xhr)"+JSON.stringify(xhr));
            alert("inside error function 2(errorType)"+errorType);
            alert("inside error function 3(exception)"+exception);
        }
    });
```

This is my spring mvc controller code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "dateVerification" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String dateVerification(@RequestParam(value="jsonDate",required=true) String jsonDate) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jsonDate);
        System.out.println("JSON Success"+jsonDate);     
       return jsonDate;
    }
```

I am not able to print this Joption and sysout in my controller.Is there anything wrong with my controller code?

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Your RequestParam is String, not JSONString.

Comment: I'm confused by the signature of your success callback function.  `jsonDate` is defined prior to making the ajax request, but it's also the parameter to the success function?  Perhaps you should be expecting the response variable in the callback function?  `success: function(response)`...

Answer (score 0):

This is really a javascript problem.  In your `success` callback function, you're receiving a parameter called `jsonDate`, but that's a variable defined above the ajax code.  `response` is undefined in the scope of the function, and that's likely the error you're seeing in the debugger.  Just change the signature of the callback function.

```
success: function(response) { // now response is defined in the scope of the function
    if (response == jsonDate)
    {
        alert("success and json passed");
    } else {
        alert("not success"+response);
    }
},
```